# Mirror modifier is spazing out

Tags: mesh, mirror, mirror-modifier

ok, so i have my mesh here and i want to mirror it, but when i do it has this weird glitch, what should i do?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The object local orientation is probably tilted compared to the global one, in that case apply the rotation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Rotation*)